# Cross browser code to restrict user input using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I found this code through Stack Overflow to restrict users from putting numbers in a textbox, however it only works in Chrome and IE. Anyone know of any cross browser code to do this?  
Note: we've already added the global attribute and it didn't work at all, this was the only one that fully worked in Chrome and IE.

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/, '')" />
```

Comment: Here's the code: <input type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/, '')" />

Comment: It appears you are doing this via Javascript as per your code example. Are you using a Javascript library like Angular or jQuery in your project? What level of browser support are you looking for? Is this purely for display or for validation or both?

Comment: have you tried using `oninput` instead?

Comment: This is working for me in Chrome, Firefox, Edge, IE and Safari.

Comment: What browsers are you testing in, What versions?

Comment: Your existing code works fine in both Safari and Firefox for me (but the `onkeyup` event may not be the best one to depend on, it looks a bit strange to have the "bad" input stay in place for a moment while typing, and I'm not certain that event will fire at all on touchscreens. `oninput` would be a better choice.

Comment: Sorry for the late response: I was testing this in the newest versions of both browsers (as of October 11th, 2017). We have tried oninput, onkeydown, etc etc and still didn't work cross browser. Interesting S. Walker that it worked for you... 
I decided to use a third party plug-in, Alpha-num, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You want to catch `onkeydown` that is when the character gets inserted, not on `onkeyup`. You should also instead of removing the number, just prevent it from getting inserted with `event.preventDefault()`

```html
<p>
  <input type="text" onkeydown="event.key.match(/\d/) && event.preventDefault()" />
</p>
```

One thing I would recommend is removing the code from the html and putting it in a function so it is reusable like this:

```js
// Wait till the dom is loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
  // Add the event to each input that has `data-type="number"`
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-type=number]').forEach(function(input) {
    // Add the event to the input
    input.addEventListener('keydown', number)
  })
})

function number(event) {
  event.key.match(/\d/) && event.preventDefault()
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="text" data-type="number" />
</p>
```

Comment: Maybe change the arrow function in the listener to a normal function in case they aren't using a transpiler for their JS?

Comment: querySelector works in IE8/9 I believe whereas the arrow functions won't.

Comment: Yeah I looked `queryselector` up on caniuse.com, it doesn't have full support on ie 8 but does on ie 9. `=>` has no ie support but is supported on edge

Comment: Good advice, except input type="number" will only allow numbers rather than prevent numbers. Also beware of unexpected behaviors with input type="number" if you go that route for anything. For instance, leading 0's will get stripped and "e" will be allowed since we only get valid/actual numbers from that type of input.

Comment: haha you are right, by the time I got to that one I was thinking they wanted numbers instead of removing them. I removed that example.